# Removing all text between two sets of characters

Tags: shell, sh

I have a text file that contains hundreds of these lines. I'd like to remove each line that is wrapped in `/*` `=`. Here's a sample:

```
/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "GET SUPPORT"; ObjectID = "2SP-lc-CRF"; */
"2SP-lc-CRF.normalTitle" = "GET SUPPORT";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "TAKE PHOTO"; ObjectID = "4Dp-dN-aZh"; */
"4Dp-dN-aZh.normalTitle" = "TAKE PHOTO";

/* Class = "UIButton"; normalTitle = "WHATSAPP"; ObjectID = "4J2-uX-p15"; */
"4J2-uX-p15.normalTitle" = "WHATSAPP";
```

so all that I'm left with is:

```
"GET SUPPORT";
"TAKE PHOTO";
"WHATSAPP";
```

I'm a shell scripting noob so I don't have much experience with text manipulation. I know some of the basic commands. Here's what I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed 's//*.**/://' Test > RESULT.txt
```

It doesn't seem to work. I'm ending up with a error:

```
 sed: 1: "s//*.**/://": bad flag in substitute command: ':'
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` to delete all `/* ... */` lines:

```
sed '/\/\*.*\*\//d; s/^.*= *//' Test > RESULT.txt
cat RESULT.txt
```

```
"GET SUPPORT";

"TAKE PHOTO";

"WHATSAPP";
```

- Note that both `/` and `*` characters are special regex meta-characters that need to be escaped.
- `/d` command deletes a line for given pattern.
- `s/^.*= *//` command removes text till `=<space>` in each remove.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake. I updated my question! I meant it to be between `/*` and `=`.

Comment: Yes, sir. "GET SUPPORT";
"TAKE PHOTO";
"WHATSAPP";

Comment: Are `=` considered special regex characters as well?

Comment: Is there an uncommented line after each commented e.g. like `"2SP-lc-CRF.normalTitle" = "GET SUPPORT";` ? And no `=` is not special character.

Comment: Yes, the pattern is `commented line` -> `"2SP-lc-CRF.normalTitle" = "GET SUPPORT";`  and then so on.

Comment: That works perfectly. I wish I understood it a little better. Thank so much!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to `sed`, you can also you `awk` to the same effect, e.g.

```
$ awk -F' = ' '/\/\*.*\*\/$/{next} /^$/{next} {print $2}' file
"GET SUPPORT";
"TAKE PHOTO";
"WHATSAPP";
```

Which essentially uses the same regular expressions to skip the lines containing comments or empty-lines with `next` only printing the second field of the lines that are not skipped.